# React Native -- Even after imports and exports are correct getting error "The component for route 'Menu' must be a react component"

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

- I have encountered the mentioned error. I searched for this through different links as.  I changed import and export according to the answer to this question but the same error is still there.  I have done imports and exports correctly.*

This is
**MainComponent.js** file where the Menu component is imported.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Dishdetail from './DishDetailComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import { View, Platform, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems, SafeAreaView, SrollView } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchLeaders } from '../redux/ActionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        dishes: state.dishes,
        promotions: state.promotions,
        leaders: state.leaders,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchDishes: () => dispatch(fetchDishes()),
    fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
    fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
    fetchLeaders: () => dispatch(fetchLeaders()),
});

const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Menu: {
            screen: Menu,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={24} color="#fff" onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />,
            }),
        },
        Dishdetail: { screen: Dishdetail },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Menu',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: '#fff',
            },
        },
    }
);

const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home },
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: '#fff',
            },
            headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={24} color="#fff" onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />,
        }),
    }
);

const ContactNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Contact: { screen: Contact },
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: '#fff',
            },
            headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={24} color="#fff" onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />,
        }),
    }
);

const AboutNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        About: { screen: About },
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: '#fff',
            },
            headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={24} color="#fff" onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />,
        }),
    }
);

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
    <ScrollView>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Image source={require('./images/logo.png')} style={styles.drawerImage} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                    <Text style={styles.drawerHeaderText}>VangooApp</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
);

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Home',
                drawerLabel: 'Home',
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="home" type="font-awesome" size={24} color={tintColor} />,
            },
        },
        About: {
            screen: AboutNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'About',
                drawerLabel: 'About Us',
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Icon name="info-circle" type="font-awesome" size={24} color={tintColor} />
                ),
            },
        },
        Menu: {
            screen: MenuNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Menu',
                drawerLabel: 'Menu',
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" type="font-awesome" size={24} color={tintColor} />,
            },
        },
        Contact: {
            screen: ContactNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Contact',
                drawerLabel: 'Contact Us',
                drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Icon name="address-card" type="font-awesome" size={22} color={tintColor} />
                ),
            },
        },
    },
    {
        drawerBackgroundColor: '#D1C4E9',
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    }
);

class MainComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchDishes();
        this.props.fetchComments();
        this.props.fetchPromos();
        this.props.fetchLeaders();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
                <MainNavigator />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    drawerHeader: {
        backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
        height: 140,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    drawerHeaderText: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    drawerImage: {
        margin: 10,
        width: 80,
        height: 60,
    },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

**MenuComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Tile } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseURL';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        dishes: state.dishes,
    };
};
class Menu extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Menu',
    };
    render() {
        const renderMenuItem = ({ item, index }) => {
            return (
                <Tile
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    caption={item.description}
                    featured
                    onPress={() => navigate('Dishdetail', { dishId: item.id })}
                    imageSrc={{ uri: baseUrl + item.image }}
                />
            );
        };
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.dishes.dishes}
                renderItem={renderMenuItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu);

[![Error][1]][1]
```

Comment: could you change the last line in the menu file to this `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Menu);`

Comment: I Tried. Still getting the same error.